# Is there a way to program a loop to go through each character in a char* array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way or method to check individual characters in an array

```
char* s[size] = {
    "0-2324-2324-7", 
    "032121353X", 
    "0-619-66248-X", 
    "0-758-50938-6", 
    "0870495275"
};
```

I would imagine I would have to write the for loop that goes through each entry in the array and the for loop that goes through each character in that entry in the array inside

kinda like:

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) 
    for (int j=0; j<"size of s[i]"; j++)  // the size of an entry so "032121353X" would be 10
        int* c= "the j character in s[i]" // assigns c the individual character in s[i]
        if(c<='0'||c>='9')  // checks if its a digit
```

Comment: So... You are sharing your ideas with us?

Comment: The expression you're looking for is `int c = s[i][j];` (no star). And in your j-loop condition you want `j < strlen(s[i]);`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was just wondering if there was something wrong with what Im doing, Im quite new to C and programming in general

Comment: _"to check individual characters in an array"_ What does this mean?

Comment: Anyway, you question should be stated in the body of your post clearly. And not in a form of "yes/no" question.

Comment: Your array loop is very inefficient. You could improve the speed of this massively.

Comment: try using modern C++, like `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need `strlen` to iterate over a string - since you're iterating over it anyway, we can avoid the double-iteration by just walking until we hit the `\0` ourselves:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
{
    // Checking for *p is equivalent to checking if p != '\0'
    // This works because of the nature of C
    for (char* p = s[i]; *p; ++p) 
    {
        if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') 
        {
            // I have a digit!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will confuse the OP even more.

Comment: +1. This is the most efficient solution. No external function calls are needed. Why use a couple of milliseconds calling a function to do something when you can do it yourself?

Comment: @SevenBits It's efficient but confusing for a programmer who can't understand pointers very well, you said **but we should be educating people in the _correct_ way to do things.** and that is how to fix their code and understand why it failed, this is just a way of showing off knowledge which will not be useful for the OP, they might even copy this code use it, and understand what it does 2 or even 3 years from today. It's of course my opinion and it can be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
{
    size_t length;

    length = strlen(s[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < length ; j++)
    {
        char c;

        c = s[i][j];
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)c) != 0)
            printf("%c is a digit\n", c);
    }
}
```

you need to include `string.h` and `ctype.h`

Comment: Comparing signed and unsigned generally generate warnings... You can pack `for` a lot... Also `isdigit(c)` is buggy, as API expects `int`, and the type expansion from char to int gives wrong values.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk what do you mean **pack** `for`?

Comment: `for (size_t j = 0, len = strlen(s[i]); j < len; ++j)`

Comment: An even faster way would be to check for `\0` at the end of the string...

Comment: Note that `strlen` will loop over the characters in the string. Perhaps there's a better way? :)

Comment: That is bad practice because it invokes `strlen()` on each call.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Noo don't use `strlen` in the `for` loop...

Comment: in my loop `strlen` is used only once... but indeed, `for (size_t j = 0; s[i][j]; ++j)`  is much shorter.

Comment: @SevenBits has a point there, that would be good, but I just wanted to fix the OP's algorithm and not to rewrite. Those things take time to get used to, and probably will confuse the OP. but sure `for (size_t j = 0 ; s[j] != '\0' ; ++j)` is much shorter and more efficient too.

Comment: @iharob you still has a bug with `isdigit` call: when the character is from the upper half (negative), the call produces exception (on win32/msvc), because correct expansion is: `isdigit((unsigned char)c)`

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk why would the character be negative?

Comment: @iharob True, but we should be educating people in the *correct* way to do things.

Comment: @SevenBits absolutely right, now I would be irrespectful if I don't change it.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk `char` values are almost always positive, for this reason many people use `unsigned char` (and `char` is unsigned on many platforms).

Comment: @iharob if it is non-ascii encoding (i.e. utf8, latin1 or another actually used), the value can be negative...

Comment: @SevenBits when I write text in my native language, they are almost always negative... Or half of them, depending on encoding used.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Hence why I said `char` values are **almost always** positive. But you're absolutely right.

Comment: the c = s[i][j] statement is giving me an error

this is what I have for reference:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/90efb9d204633e5a4756

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` loops over the string, which is redundant. Instead...

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    char *p = s[i];
    char c;
    while ((c = *p++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(c) != 0)
            printf("%c is a digit\n", c);
    }
}
```